# Container frame returns incorrect size in viewDidLoad but correctly in viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I am using container view in my application.

Consider this container to be of size of `721*1024`.

I use `performSegueWithIdentifier` method to push my container view controller.
When i print out the view's frame size in viewDidLoad it shows me the `768*1024` and same view's frame size is shown `721*1024` in `viewWillAppear`,why?

What is going wrong? I am trying to add some subviews in this container view,also i have used autoresizing in my application.So when the subview is added in `viewDidLoad` method,the frames don't get resized properly because they take the wrong frames from `viewDidLoad`.
My main question is why is container view's frame displayed incorrectly in `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: The container is not set up in `-viewDidLoad` and is probably not in the view hierarchy at all at that point. If you need to know the size of a view for layout reasons, uses `-viewDidLayoutSubviews` but remember to read all the docs regarding that if you're using auto layout.

Comment: @Jason Coco So are saying i have to add the subviews in viewDidLayoutSubviews method? and i am not using autolayout,i am using autoresizing